# Reversible string transformation

Tags: c++, string

I have a string returned from an external C++ lib after saving a record.

This string is a key to be used if you want to retrieve the saved record via the lib.

I would like to hide the specific key format returned by the lib and return something like a hash code to the user, so that the user can use this key string to query the saved record from the system.

The key string transformation should be reversible as I still need the original value to communicate with the external lib. In this case, a Hash code is not appropriate.

The questions I would like to ask:

1. Is there any existing standard lib to do that?
2. As it is a key to the user directly, if possible, I would like it to be a string of printable chars.
3. It seems that encryption and decryption is my best choice? If so, which algo/lib is suggested? A simple code example is enough.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you think is a "hash code", i.e. what characteristics does it have? Why would you sacrifice a unique key for a possibly duplicate hash value, assuming you use actual hashing? Why isn't the key in its form presentable to the user?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I do not want to sacrifice a unique key for it (Also, hashing is not reversible in general.), that is why I said hashing is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to *obfuscate* the string so that the user can't use it directly.  The question is, how obfuscated does it need to be?  If a trivial amount of obfuscation is all that is required, there are any number of simple algorithms that can do that (ROT13, XOR, nybbleizing, etc).  You could combine them or come up with your own, although keep in mind that if you release an executable or library containing the algorithm, then any sufficiently determined user could reverse-engineer the algorithm or step through your code with a debugger to figure it out, if they really wanted to.

If it's really important that nobody figure it out, then the best thing to do is to never give the user the obfuscated information or the algorithm at all.  For that, you could simply create a unique ID for each string (e.g. by computing a sufficiently large hash code) and store the mapping between generated IDs and their source-strings on a server that you control.  Then you only give your user the generated ID, which he later hands back to your server, and your servers looks up the corresponding original string in its database.  (That's pretty much the algorithm that sites like TinyURL.com use, FWIW).

Another option would be to use something like OpenSSL's libcrypto to encrypt the string using a secret key, then nybbleize or base64-encode the encrypted output and pass the results back to the user.  That would avoid the need to maintain a database, but of course it only remains secure if the secret key is secure, which means it still needs to be done on a computer you control rather than on the user's computer, otherwise the user can simply run a debugger to find out what the secret encryption/decryption key is, and you're back to square one.

Comment: indeed, security is not a main concern for me and also the application is hosted as a web service in my side. It should be ok. It looks like to me that the a simple encryption/compression with a baseXX-encode can serve my purpose and easy enough to implement. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apart from some encryption or obfuscation (which is essentially an easy-to-break encryption), you could also compress, then stringify (and de-stringify, then decompress the other way around). If your keys are long, this might even be a usability improvement for your users.

A de-facto standard for compression is the [zlib library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) and for de/stringification you could use Base64 or Base85, which are also pretty standard, with several open source library implementations.

Comment: Thanks, your idea is basically similar with Jeremy'one and also remind me about the usability when I have a very long key. I cannot accept 2 answers so I upvoted your one.